# Qlik sense: Exclude weekends on a date dimension

Tags: business-intelligence, qliksense

I want to remove weekend days on my dimension. Now the dimension is created by the autocalendar [ActualEnd.autoCalendarr.Date]. I'm trying functions like WeekDay but is not working. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WeekDay` gives you the number of the day in a week. If you use a conditional (`if`) you can remove weekdays:

`if(not(WeekDay(date_field)=5 or WeekDay(date_field)=6), date_field)`